# The right way to insert a parent/child record in sequelize with the same transaction (get parent ID)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In sequelize how do we get the parent id to update the child record in the same transactions. I am trying this way but it just fails to get the ID of the parent.

```
db.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
  return db.Employee.create(employeeData, {transaction:t}).then(function(newEmployee)
  {
//how to get the parent ID here?
    var empDetailData = {x: "", y: "", emp_id:newEmployee.id};
    return db.EmployeeDetails.create(empDetailData, {transaction:t}).then(function(newDetail)
    {
        res.json(newEmployee);
    });
  });
});
```

**DB relation**

```
Employee.hasMany(EmployeeDetails, {foreignKey:'emp_id'});
```

It errors out saying emp_id cannot be null. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  How can I get the id so the transaction can work.

**SOLVED**: The actual issue was the db code was missing autoIncrement: true

```
id: {
  type:  Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  **autoIncrement: true** was missing. 
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is `t.commit()` & `t.rollback()`. You need `newEmployee` inside the promise chain of `newDetails`, which introduce [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) in promise callback chain. A much neat version using `Async/Await` is given following with `t.commit()` and `t.rollback()`.

```
async function createUser(employeeData) {
  let transaction;
  try {

    transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction();

    const newEmployee = await db.Employee.create( employeeData, {
      transaction: transaction
    })
    const empDetailData = {
      x: "",
      y: "",
      emp_id:newEmployee.id
    };
    await db.EmployeeDetails.create(empDetailData, {
      transaction: transaction
    })

    await transaction.commit()

    res.json(newEmployee)

  } catch(error) {
    if(transaction) {
      await transaction.rollback()
    }
    // HANDLE THE ERROR AS YOU MANAGE IN YOUR PROJECT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
createUserWithDetails = async(data) => {
        try {
            const transaction = await db.sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
                      let newEmp = await db.Employee.create(employeeData,{transaction:t});
                      let empDetailData = {x: "", y: "", emp_id: newEmp.id};
                      let details = await db.EmployeeDetails.create(empDetailData, {transaction:t});

            // If you've made it so far everything is ok and
            // the transaction will be automatically committed.
            res.json(newEmp);

            });

            return transaction;
        }
        catch(error) {
            // Handle Error
            // The transaction is automatically rollbacked!
        }
```